# Problem inserting checkbox in select using DataTables

Tags: select, search, checkbox, datatables

I'm looking for a way to insert a checkbox into a select and fetch each column individually, all using DataTables. I found an excellent example in https://jsfiddle.net/Lxytynm3/2/ but for some reason, when selecting all records, filtering does not display the data as expected. Would anyone have a solution to work properly?
Thanks in advance.
The link application code is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  function cbDropdown(column) {
    return $('<ul>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown'
    }).appendTo($('<div>', {
      'class': 'cb-dropdown-wrap'
    }).appendTo(column));
  }

  $('#example').DataTable({
    initComplete: function() {
      this.api().columns().every(function() {
        var column = this;
        var ddmenu = cbDropdown($(column.header()))

          // -------------------------------------------------------

          .on('change', ':checkbox', function() {
            var active;
            var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
              active = true;
              return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
            }).toArray().join('|');

            column
              .search(vals.length > 0 ? '^(' + vals + ')$' : '', true, false)
              .draw();

            // -------------------------------------------------------
            // Highlight the current item if selected.
            if (this.checked) {
              $(this).closest('li').addClass('active');

              // If 'Select all / none' clicked ON
              if ($(this).val() === "1") {


                $(ddmenu).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked)
                //$(".cb-dropdown li").prop('checked', true);
                //$('.cb-dropdown').closest('li').find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);
                // $('this input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', true);    works!
                // $( 'input[type="checkbox"]' ).prop('checked', this.checked);
                // $(this).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked)
                //$('div.cb-dropdown-wrap.active').children().find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', this.checked)

              }
            } else // 'Select all / none' clicked OFF

            {
              $(this).closest('li').removeClass('active');
              // test if select none
              if ($(this).val() === "1") {
                // code to untick all
                $(ddmenu).find('input[type="checkbox"]').prop('checked', false)
              }
            }

            // Highlight the current filter if selected.
            var active2 = ddmenu.parent().is('.active');
            if (active && !active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().addClass('active');

              // Change Container title to "Filter on" and green
              //$(this).parent().find('.cb-dropdown li:nth-child(n+1)').css('color','red');   
              $('active2 li label:contains("Filter OFF")').text('Yeees');

            } else if (!active && active2) {
              ddmenu.parent().removeClass('active');
            }
          });

        // -------------------------------------------------------
        var mytopcount = '0'; // Counter that ensures only 1 entry per container

        // loop to assign all options in container filter
        column.data().unique().sort().each(function(d, j) {

          // Label
          var $label = $('<label>'),
            $text = $('<span>', {
              text: d
            }),

            // Checkbox
            $cb = $('<input>', {
              type: 'checkbox',
              value: d
            });


          $text.appendTo($label);
          $cb.appendTo($label);

          ddmenu.append($('<li>').append($label));


          // -----------------
          // Add 'Select all / none' to each dropdown container
          if (mytopcount == '0') // Counter that ensures only 1 entry per container
          {
            $label = $('<label>'), $text = $('<span>', {
                text: "Select all / none"
              }),

              $cb = $('<input>', {
                type: 'checkbox',
                value: 1
              });

            $text.prependTo($label).css('margin-bottom', '6px');
            $cb.prependTo($label);
            ddmenu.prepend($('<li>').prepend($label).css({
              'border-bottom': '1px solid grey',
              'margin-bottom': '6px'
            }));

            mytopcount = '1' // This stops this section running again in cotainer 

          }

        });

      });
    }
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems as though the issue was with the select all checkbox. One solution would be to check for "1" within the `vals` initialisation, this seems to work:

```
var vals = $(':checked', ddmenu).map(function(index, element) {
    if($(element).val() !== "1"){
        return $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex($(element).val());
    }
}).toArray().join('|');
```

That should see you with some results upon the top checkbox being checked. Hope that helps.

Comment: Dear annoyingmouse, you have no idea how your solution helped me. Thankfully, there are people like you who use their time to help us. Thank you very much.